# how to escape special characters in c# and jquery?

Tags: c#, jquery, json

i want to escpae a "<" for returning result ,it's a list containing id id object and in conditions i want to add a special characters "< "to be replaced  for returning result:

```
public class FormatObject {

    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int IdObject { get; set; }

    public string Conditions { get; set; }

    public List<int> SelectedAttributesId { get; set; }

    public override string ToString() {
        
        string result = "[" + Id + "," + IdObject + ", \"" +  Conditions + "\"";
        if (SelectedAttributesId != null)
            result += ", [" + string.Join(",", SelectedAttributesId.ToArray()) + "]";

        return result + "]";

        

    }
   
}
```

}
jquery:

```
 obj.$el.find('select').addClass('select-sm').select2({ dropdownAutoWidth: 'true', width: 'resolve', tag: true }); //, width: '100%'
            obj.$el.find('input:not(:checkbox)').addClass('input-sm');//it'sthe lline for escape special characters but no working for me
            obj.$el.find('input:checkbox').addClass('checkbox');
```

search/getsjsonforquery:

```
public JsonResult GetJsonForQuery(ObjectJson serializedJson) {
            
            
            if (serializedJson.MainObjects ==null){
                JsonResult result = Json(new { updated = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("o"), errorNoItemSelected = true  },JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
                result.MaxJsonLength = Int32.MaxValue;
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(serializedJson.MainObjects); 
                return result;
                
            }
```

Comment: Use Regex.Escape https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.escape?view=net-5.0

Comment: Manually creating JSON is a really bad idea and error prone due to such issues as escaping and making sure quotes and braces are all properly matched. Most languages have json serializing and parsing methods